# How to export item from drop down in django-admin

Tags: django, python-3.x, export-to-excel

I have a module Project with drop down lists, and inside of Project I have project names , like Project1, Project2, Project3 etc..
So , when I export to xls or csv , I got integer instead of names.
For example, when I export list, I got 1 or 3 or any other number instead of name Project1 or Project3 etc..
How can I solve this ?
I couldn't find any answer about that, and I would appreciate any answer.

This is my class

```
class Person(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, default=None,)
```

Comment: Can you share the code that does the export?

Comment: Well I don't have any code, cause I am trying to use django import_export. But I couldn't find any solution. 
Even I have installed import_export from github, but it is the same thing... https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export.git
They have Categories in lists (ManyToMany) and when its export to xls the column of Category 1 is integer. I don't know how to solve this issues.